# Compare and insert row (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying my excel file to:

Compare columns G and H
- If they have the same text -> go to the next row to continue the comparison
- If they don't have the same text -> Insert a row below G and then continue the comparison.

The result would be this:

*Before running the macro* (first column is G, second column is H):

[image: http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/5196/c49u.jpg]

*After running the macro:*

[image: http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/9527/dwkj.jpg]

Can you help me with this, please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Post your code to show us what you have so far.

Comment: I don't even know if I'm in the good path: Dim lCounter As Long '<-- 'ALIGN COLUMNS

lCounter = 11 'set this to the first row number
Do While Range("H" & lCounter).Value <> "" And Range("I" & lCounter).Value <> ""
    If Range("H" & lCounter).Value <> Range("I" & lCounter) Then
        Range("H" & lCounter & ":A" & lCounter).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If
lCounter = lCounter + 1
Loop

Comment: By the way, the colums there are different, I'm working with another document now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
Sub CompArray()
Dim G
Dim H
Dim X
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim lngMark As Long

G = Range([g1], Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
H = Range([H1], Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
X = H

For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
If G(lngCnt - lngMark, 1) = H(lngCnt, 1) Then
X(lngCnt, 1) = G(lngCnt - lngMark, 1)
Else
lngMark = lngMark + 1
X(lngCnt, 1) = vbNullString
End If
Next

[g1].Resize(UBound(X), 1) = X

End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot make it work so far, it enters in an infinite loop, but I can start working with this. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Is your data as you have shown in your sample? My code will run for as many cells are present in column G

Comment: Yeah, it is the same. In fact it was not an infinite loop, that happened with the other code, sorry. Copy/pasting your code and running it deletes everythin in column G.

Comment: That sounds part right, column G should be updated to match H - unless there end up being no matches once the rows are inserted.

Comment: About the question with the DATA, it is not exactly like that. It may happens a value in G is not present in H. I don't know if it is making to delete all the column, though.

Comment: In the first example, all values in column G are present in H, so it is working perfectly. In the second file, there is two values in G not present in H, so it stops working.

Comment: How did you want to handle this update (non-existing G values)?

Comment: It should enter a new cell below. The final go is to have both columns shorted out. TEST1 in G should be next to TEST1 in H. TEST1ALT is not present in G, so it appears blank there. And TEST9B is not present in H, so it should appear blank there. the rest of them, in this way, are sorted out and each of them next to the other.

Comment: Basically, and if I am not wrong, the same behavior but in the other way.

Comment: So it seems finally I made it work! :) The only thing left it to make the formula start on row 11 instead of one and it is done. Thanks a lot for your help, I would not have been able to do it without your help. (I cannot paste the formula, it says it is too long :/ )

Answer (score 0):

You can select the range you want to look at and then loop through the rows.
Compare the cells, if they are not the same, select the right cell.
Then insert in new cell and move everything to 1 cell down
This code s a bit slow, because it selects the whole column. 
You can change compare statement to make a different compare

```
Dim rngCompare As Range
Dim rowCount As Long
Dim iCount As Long

Set rngCompare = ActiveSheet.Columns("D:E")
rowCount = rngCompare.Rows.Count
For iCount = 1 To rowCount
If StrComp(rngCompare.Cells(iCount, 1), rngCompare.Cells(iCount, 2), vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
    rngCompare.Cells(iCount, 1).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

End If
Next iCount
```

Comment: Hey, it does not matter if it is taking a while. :) But what it does is asking me if I want to continue because the operation will cause some merged cells to unmerge, and then move the fourth column down in an infinite loop.

Comment: It seems it works if all the values in G are present in H. But when a value in G is not present, it starts to insert white rows in an infinite loop.