# Comparing columns and inserting a row from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Im new to this forum, VBA and macro's in general and have been trying to get around with some things I found here. Hopefully this post is clear and not spammy.

Im looking for a macro that is able to compare cells in column A and B and insert a row from another sheet (or another excel document). I will add images to illustrate it.

[Examplesheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QshM.png)
[Examplesheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQLyj.png)

In the first image you can see that column A has more cells and the difference are the cells with 'Dont know'. I want to insert the cells from another sheet (second image) into the first sheet if the cells in column A and B do not match. The result I am looking for is shown in the third image.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Wyf.png)

I tried to solve my problem with the link below. Unfortunately this macro "only" compares columns and moves those cells down and I have not been able to alter this macro to serve my needs.

My thought process so far:

- Column A from sheet 1 and sheet 2 are identical as it is a copy-paste, Column B from sheet1 (image1) is a shorter version of Column A and needs to be exactly the same size as Column A.
- The rows I would like to be inserted are starting (on the compared row of sheet1) at Column A on sheet2 and can contain cells until XX. (would be nice if this is configurable like A:AB for the compared row)
- The comparing of columns should be done first, if a difference in the cells is found, a row should be inserted from Column B to Column XX in sheet1 (as configurable like the previous bullet).
- After column A is fully checked (could be 100s or 1000s of cells), the corresponding rows from sheet2 should be copied.

[Compare and insert row (VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404408/compare-and-insert-row-vba?newreg=6a6b6d5152b8429192f371ff78d8a9f1)

```
Dim A
Dim B
Dim X
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim lngMark As Long

A = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
B = Range([B1], Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
X = B

For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
If A(lngCnt - lngMark, 1) = B(lngCnt, 1) Then
X(lngCnt, 1) = A(lngCnt - lngMark, 1)
Else
lngMark = lngMark + 1
X(lngCnt, 1) = vbNullString
End If
Next

[a1].Resize(UBound(X), 1) = X

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to find what's missing, so you would want to have a loop from "Question 2" to "Question 3", etc., to ensure you have all of the appropriate labels and data included.  You essentially don't need to shift cells before you copy over, you can insert the missing info.

Answer (score 0):

quick mock-up, untested, in support of my comment:

```
dim questionNum as long
for questionNum = 1 to 10
    with sheets(1)
        dim startRow as long
        startRow = .columns(2).find("Question " & questionNum).row
        dim endRow as long
        endRow = .columns(2).find("Question " & questionNum+1).row 'need an error check when you past last question
        dim secondSheetQuestionNum as long
        secondSheetQuestionNum = sheets(2).find("Question " & questionNum).row
        dim resultCheckRow as long
        for resultCheckRow = startRow to endRow
            if NOT .cells(resultCheckRow,2).value = sheets(2).cells(secondSheetQuestionNum,1).value then
                sheets(2).range(sheets(2).cells(secondSheetQuestionNum,2),sheets(2).cells(secondSheetQuestionNum,10)).copy
                .range(.cells(resultsCheckRow,2),.cells(resultsChecKRow,10)).insert xlshiftdown
            end if
            secondSheetQuestionNum = secondSheetQuestionNum  +1
        next resultCheckRow
    end with
next questionNum
```

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly! The "question 2" etc. are used to illustrate and the real data has actual sentences/questions. Like "How satisfied are you with....". I think this matters for your code? I do think that I understand what direction you are going with this.

Comment: It does matter for what's written in my example, though those can be filled with looping through an array of your questions, etc.  Essentially you need to verify that for the same question found on the source data sheet, you have the same data on your results sheet.  I tried to use variable names to be descriptive of intent, so hopefully that makes it easier to understand.